# How to add an incremental constrain based on after executing subset in cplex?

Tags: cplex

How to add the below constraint as an incremental constraint because it depends on {inner_beams} subset which is an after executing subset. The below code is not working

```
                        //I have tried the below main but it's not working
Main {
      for(i in thisOplModel.inner_beams) 
     {
       thisOplModel.const02[i].setCoef(thisOplModel.beam_firstchannel[i-1],1);
       thisOplModel.const02[i].setCoef(thisOplModel.beam_nomusedchannel[i-1],1);
thisOplModel.const02[i].setBounds(thisOplModel.beam_firstchannel[i],thisOplModel.beam_firstchannel[i]);   
     }  
     cplex.solve();
     thisOplModel.postProcess(); 
}

 
Subject to
{
const02:
 forall (i in beams: i in inner_beams) //Not working because the inner beams is not calculated yet
 (beam_firstchannel[i]==beam_firstchannel[i-1]+ beam_nomusedchannel[i-1]); 
}

{int} inner_beams={2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13};  // this is the results of the after executing set
```

Comment: @Alexfleischer it gives me an error of Unknown property 2.

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/enumerate.mod

```
    dvar int xy; // in order to find all solutions
    dvar int x in 0..2;
    dvar int y in 0..2;
        
    maximize xy;
    subject to
    {
      x+y<=3;
        
      xy==1000*x+y;
    }
    execute
    {
     writeln("x=",x,"   and y=",y);
    }
    main {
     var nbsol=0;
     thisOplModel.generate();
     while (1==cplex.solve())
     {
         thisOplModel.postProcess();
         nbsol++;
         thisOplModel.xy.UB=thisOplModel.xy.solutionValue-1;              
     }
            writeln("nb solutions = ",nbsol);
    }
```

You can see how to get the output of the model in order to do some incremental change.

But when changes are too important for incremental changes , it could be easier to regenerate.

See https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithoplchange/blob/master/changeset.mod

Comment: Thats what i did in the above code still gives me an error what is the problem with the above code?

Comment: You define inner_beams in the postprocess but you should do that in the preprocess if you want to use that in the subject to block